# PHP/MySQL update, ignore empty/blank values

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm quite new to PHP/MySQL and need help with an update form.

I get the values from a form and in the update query i only want to update the fields that are not empty where id = $id.

Example;

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c = $_POST['c'];

$1 = $_POST['number1'];
$2 = $_POST['number2'];
$3 = $_POST['number3'];

$sql = "UPDATE table SET a='$a', b='$b', c='$c' WHERE number='$1' OR number='$2' OR number='$3' ";
```

But if $b is empty or null it should be excluded from the update string, but $a and $c should be updated with the new value. The allredy existing value for $b should remain in the table.

Regards,
Chrickis

Comment: invalide name of variable $1 wtf?

Comment: Variables cannot start with numbers.

Comment: Read the official doc about [naming conventions of variables](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php). And please (please!) escape user input!

Comment: set the columns not null.

Comment: You should read up on sql injection, taking form input directly into a query can result in security holes. Look into either MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: It was an example.. The code is quite different, no variables with numbers in beginning.. 
Fredd; the webpage is only on a local network, so I don't think the people accessing the network even know about how to. :)

Answer (score 0):

chrickis, you should follow the php norms while write code but for your issue you can make the below changes in

```
$condition = ''; //create new varible

$b = isset($_POST['b'])?$_POST['b']:""; //check for data in field b

if($b){ $condition = "b='".$b."', "; } //write sql condition if $b has any value

 $sql = "UPDATE table SET a='$a', ".$condition." c='$c' WHERE number='$1' OR number='$2' OR number='$3' "; //modify sql
```

Comment: chrickis, if it works for you than mark this answer as right so that other user can also consider this example.

Answer (score -1):

What I would suggest is first check all the values parsed and on that basis code php to make a update query.